# How do I move a large group of emails from a "searched" group to a specific folder I have previously created?

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels, gmail-search

The easiest way, which was 1. to search for your emails 2. select the emails you would like to move and then 3. hover over the folder button with the down arrow on it, has been removed.

Now you must 1. search for the emails 2. select the ones you want to move 3. label them with the appropriate label 4. right click on the label you just created 5. click move to 6. choose the folder you would like to move the emails to.